# How to invert borderRadius in React Native?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to achieve this shaped `<View>` or `<Svg>`.

Note: I don't want to used this shaped image. The image should get masked on the shape.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

check this example using SVG and Path tweek the path to get the proper output that you want

[Snack Link](https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/a115cd)

code:

```
const TopBar = () => {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();
  const path = React.useMemo(
    () =>
      [
        'M 0 0',
        `V${barHeight/2.5}`,
        `C ${0} ${barHeight/2.5}, 0 ${barHeight-40}, ${width/2} ${barHeight-40}`,
        `S ${width} ${barHeight}, ${width} ${barHeight}`,
        'V0',
        'H0',
        'Z',
      ].join(' '),
    []
  );

  return (
    <Svg width={width} height={barHeight}>
      <Path fill="black" stroke="black" d={path} />
    </Svg>
  );
};
```

[image: ][1]]

Comment: Thank You the problem was half solved tho because had to add image to the Path made which I solved.

Comment: if u want to mask image then use masked view and maskt eh image with the svg path ot use image , mask from svg to handle the maske

Answer (score 0):

You can just ask the designer to send it in SVG and use this package: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-svg

or

Create shape using CSS, follow the link - https://codedaily.io/tutorials/The-Shapes-of-React-Native